# Setting up foreach in WordPress widget

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

I'm stuck with writing foreach loop for my link widget.

I did the var_export ($instance, true) and the output is

```
 'title' => ' Widget title',
 'image1' => 'img url',
 'link_title1' => 'Some link title',
 'target_type1' => '1',
 'link_url1' => 'some url',
 'image2' => '',
 'link_title2' => 'Some link title',
 'target_type2' => '1',
 'link_url2' => 'some url',
 'image3' => 'img url',
 'link_title3' => 'Some link title',
 'link_url3' => '',
 'image4' => 'img url',
 'link_title4' => 'Some link title',
 'link_url4' => '',
 'image5' => '',
 'link_title5' => 'Some link title',
 'link_url5' => '',
```

And so until the values reach number 10. My preferred output would be:

```
echo '<li>';
    if ($instance{'target_type' . $i} == 0) {
        echo '<img src=" '.$instance{'image' . $i} .' "><a href=" '. $instance{'link_url' . $i} .' ">' . $instance{'link_title' . $i} . '</a>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<img src=" '.$instance{'image' . $i} .' "><a href=" '. $instance{'link_url' . $i} .' " target="_blank">' . $instance{'link_title' . $i} . '</a>';
    }
echo '</li>';
```

But I don't have any idea how to set up the foreach array as value to get working.

Comment: Try using `[..]` instead of `{}` in `if()`

Comment: and what should I insert in foreach( $array as $value )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it seems what you're looking for is a `for` loop, not `foreach`:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; ++$i) {
    echo '<li>';
    if ($instance['target_type' . $i] === '0') {
        echo '<img src="' . $instance['image' . $i] . '"><a href="' . $instance['link_url' . $i] . '">' . $instance['link_title' . $i] . '</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<img src="' . $instance['image' . $i] . '"><a href="' . $instance['link_url' . $i] . '" target="_blank">' . $instance['link_title' . $i] . '</a>';
    }
    echo '</li>';
}
```

This loop will count from $i = 1 to $i = 10. Looks like this is your intent...

Comment: I had a for loop, but I started to look for a foreach loop, because the for loop prints out the empty rows as well (I have a border-bottom assigned to li). Or is there a way to hide the empty ones?

Comment: @Dariusz use a conditional to check if they are empty. If you know `foreach` and `for`, you should know how to use an `if`. Here's help

Just before the first `echo '<li>';` add

`if (empty($instance['image' . $i])) { continue; }`

Comment: Still learning, I was putting yesterday the !empy after the first `echo '<li>';` and not before. Thank you :)

Comment: @Dariusz If you want to test if multiple attributes are empty, you can do as  Ovidash suggests, and additionally specify multiple conditions separated by `||` like: `empty($instance['image' . $i]) || empty($instance['link_url' . $i])` and so on...